# What type of SharePoint List does this icon represent?

Tags: 2010, list, workflow

I've been tasked with cleaning up a SharePoint 2010 site that has become a mess.

My first step is to identify what each of the 443 Libraries and Lists actually do and whether they're still required. Unfortunately, I've hit my first snag - There is one list I can't make sense of. In the list of *All Site Content* it has this icon next to the name:

[image]

My apologies for the quality of the screenshot.

- **Does anyone know what this icon denotes?**
- **Is it some sort of Workflow list or something else?**

Comment: Workflow history! in which you can track down your created workflows , block play, stop as required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is workflow History List Icon. The image url path is

```
_layouts/15/images/itwfh.png?rev=44
```